# Error in loop to remove recycler view items. (making a loop crashes app)

Tags: java, android, loops, android-recyclerview

Existing code:

```
int length = MyData.dates.length;
            for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
                View x = mRecyclerView.getChildAt(i);
                if(x != null) {
                    length--;
                    //if(MyData.dates[i].before(today)){
                        RecyclerView.ViewHolder mViewHolder = mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForPosition(i);
                            TextView textViewName = (TextView) mViewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMatch);
                            String selectedName = (String) textViewName.getText();
                            int selectedItemId = -1;
                            if (selectedName.equals(MyData.matchArray[i])) {
                                selectedItemId = MyData.id_[i];
                            }
                            removedItems.add(selectedItemId);
                            matches.remove(i);
                            mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(i);
                    //}
                }
            }
```

When i run the function my app crashes. The reason is: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2`

making the value of i = 1 makes this function perfectly. What is the reason for this and how can I make the loop actually loop?

Arrays:

```
static String[] timingArray = {"JAN-15-2015","JAN-18-2015","JAN-25-2015","JAN-19-2015"};
static Integer[] id_ = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
static Date[] dates = new Date[timingArray.length];
```

I have other arrays which, i dont think are causing trouble.

The project is based on the tutorial: [THIS](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/android-s-recyclerview-and-cardview-widgets.html)

And remove on click works fine.

Error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
        at com.wc.gap.worldcupfixture.MainActivity.onSectionAttached(MainActivity.java:186)
        at com.wc.gap.worldcupfixture.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onAttach(MainActivity.java:294)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `for( int j ...`? j isn't used anywhere.

Comment: Indicate the line of the IOOB and how the arrays are created.

Comment: I decided to not use j and never deleted it. Anyway it doesnt bother anything.
The error is in the line: `matches.remove(i);` (what is IOOB?)

Comment: Posting code that contains erratic leftovers isn't nice. IOOB = IndexOutOfBounds. -- So what is matches? How is it created?

Comment: Oh terribly sorry about that.
should i post my entire code? (which hasnt been tidied up yet)
matches is: matches = new ArrayList<>(); The array for the recycler list

Comment: OK - check how matches is filled with values - I'm assuming it has a size() equal to MyData.dates.length before the i-loop is entered. See my updated answer.

Comment: So far it is like that. But i might change it. (although in my case i think it's going to be better to retrieve all items before removing them since i have many functions which remove different amounts of items)
the length of both arrays are the same when the loop starts, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a loop

```
for( int i = 0; i < some.length; ++i ){
    // ...
    someList.remove( i );

}
```

this is almost bound to run into an IndexOutOfBounds since `someList` is shortened at each iteration, and successive values of i will exceed the maximum available index.

Working around could be done by using decreasing index values.

Comment: Riiight. So what's a workaround? I cant use matches,length probably because it has a variable length

Comment: One proposal is added to the answer. Other options are more complicated, e.g., copy remaining elements to a new list and replace the old.